# Error armando archivo con resultado consulta nodejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql-server, nodejs

Estoy consultando una base de datos en sqlserver y necesito insertar el resultado en una tabla en base de datos mysql y otra postgresql.  He pensado hacerlo consultando la base de datos sqlserver y los resultados escribirlos en un .txt
Luego, con otra funcion de inserción, leer ese archivo y hacer los inserts en las otras base de datos.
El codigo que hace la lectura de sqlserver es el siguiente:

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

//  var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var fs = require('fs');

//  app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
   
    var sql = require("mssql");

    // config for your database
    var config = {
        server: '192.168.1.1',
        authentication: {
          type: 'default',
          options: {
            userName: 'sa',
            password: 'password'
          }
        }
    }; 

    // connect to your database
    sql.connect(config, function (err) {

        var consulta = "SELECT TOP(5) em.id_empleado, em.des_empleado, em.cargo, al.cod_almacen, sum(T1.venta) as venta FROM DB.fact.venta as T1 LEFT JOIN DB.dim.almacen as al ON T1.id_almacen = al.id_almacen INNER JOIN DB.dim.empleado as em ON T1.id_empleado = em.id_empleado WHERE vendedor='SI' AND fecha_egreso IS NULL AND cod_empleado != '-1' AND id_calendario between 20190401 AND 20190431 GROUP BY em.id_empleado, des_empleado, cargo, cod_almacen";
        
    
        if (err) console.log(err);

        // create Request object
        var request = new sql.Request();
        
           
        // query to the database and get the records
        request.query(consulta, function (err, recordset) {
            
            if (err) console.log(err)

            // send records as a response
            res.send(recordset.recordset);
            var result = recordset.recordset; 
           // console.log(recordset.recordset);

        
            fs.appendFile('newfile.txt', result, function (err) {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log('File is created successfully.');
            }); 
           
            sql.close();
        });

        

        
    });

   
});

var server = app.listen(5000, function () {
    console.log('Server is running..');
});
```

Este me da error al tratar de escribir el resultado en el archi .txt me escribe:
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
que son las 5 filas resultantes de la consulta. ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?  Cómo hago para que me escriba lo mismo que en la consola:
       [

```html
 { id_empleado: 130,
    des_empleado: 'ROBERT P',
    cargo: 'VENDEDOR FULLTIME 1',
    cod_almacen: '109',
    venta: 12268498 },
   { id_empleado: 315,
    des_empleado: 'EVA R',
    cargo: 'SUBJEFE (A)  DE TIENDA',
    cod_almacen: '030',
    venta: 7678140 },
  { id_empleado: 3192,
    des_empleado: 'DANNYE M',
    cargo: 'VENDEDOR FULL TIME 2',
    cod_almacen: '218',
    venta: 4801572.999999 },
  { id_empleado: 197,
    des_empleado: 'DORA M',
    cargo: 'VENDEDOR FULL TIME 2',
    cod_almacen: '141',
    venta: 4149077 },
  { id_empleado: 1207,
    des_empleado: 'KATHERINE T ',
    cargo: 'VENDEDOR FULLTIME 1',
    cod_almacen: '106',
    venta: 10595596 } ]
```

Comment: Podrías realizarlo de otra manera has pensando hacer la consulta a tu base de datos sqlServer luego el resultado parsearlo y ejecutar un metodo que escriba ese resultado en tu base de datos mysql y postgres? Saludos!

Comment: @Nik020 También, pero tengo el mismo problema armando el arreglo de valores a insertar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El método appendFile de FileSystem hace el primer metodo toString() que no hace el recorrido detallado como para transformar adecuadamente array de objetos, lo que tienes que hacer antes de almacenar el archivo es transformar en texto con el metodo JSON.stringify(). Un Ejemplo para que se muestre de mejor forma.

```js
let resultado =  [{ id_empleado: 130,
    des_empleado: 'ROBERT P',
    cargo: 'VENDEDOR FULLTIME 1',
    cod_almacen: '109',
    venta: 12268498 },
   { id_empleado: 315,
    des_empleado: 'EVA R',
    cargo: 'SUBJEFE (A)  DE TIENDA',
    cod_almacen: '030',
    venta: 7678140 },
  { id_empleado: 3192,
    des_empleado: 'DANNYE M',
    cargo: 'VENDEDOR FULL TIME 2',
    cod_almacen: '218',
    venta: 4801572.999999 },
  { id_empleado: 197,
    des_empleado: 'DORA M',
    cargo: 'VENDEDOR FULL TIME 2',
    cod_almacen: '141',
    venta: 4149077 },
  { id_empleado: 1207,
    des_empleado: 'KATHERINE T ',
    cargo: 'VENDEDOR FULLTIME 1',
    cod_almacen: '106',
    venta: 10595596 }];
    
 let resultadoNoRequerido = resultado.toString();
 console.log(`El resultado con el que trabaja actualmente es: ${resultadoNoRequerido}`);
 
 let resultadoRequerido = JSON.stringify(resultado);
  console.log(`El resultado que desea es: ${resultadoRequerido}`);
```